# How to avoid threads to starve

Tags: java, multithreading

Suppose I have a hotel with m Rooms.

Guests (Threads) come in and out the whole time.

A Room can have lots of people inside, but only one Room will have people. For example:

- Guest A (wants Room 1)
- Guest B (wants Room 2)
- Guest C (wants Room 1)

  A can go to Room 1, once all rooms are empty;

  B cannot go to Room 2 yet, given that there is another room with people still inside;

  C can go to Room 1, because the Room C wants is the only Room with people inside;
- Given that A and C leave Room 1, B should be able to go to Room 2
- The last Guest to exit a room should stop every other Guests (avoiding them to come in while he is coming out) until it leaves, so the others can continue

How can I implement this somehow the threads will not starve?

For simplicity, suppose that, once the Guest comes inside a room, it sleeps for some seconds and then get out. Here is my (wrong) implementation:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;

public class Guest extends Thread {
    static Rooms rooms = new Rooms(5);

    int id;

    Guest(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public void run() {

        rooms.join(this);

        nap();

        rooms.quit(this);
    }

    public void nap() {
        try {
            sleep((new Random().nextInt(4000) + 1000));
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {

            Thread t = new Guest(i);
            t.start();

            Thread.sleep((long) new Random().nextInt(1500) + 1000);

        }

    }

}

class Rooms {

    Room[] rooms;
    int busy;

    Rooms(int m) {
        busy = -1;
        rooms = new Room[m + 1];
        for (int i = 0; i < m + 1; i++)
            rooms[i] = new Room();
    }

    void join(Guest h) {
        if (busy == -1) {
            busy = (new Random().nextInt(rooms.length));
        }

        rooms[busy].add(h);

        System.out.println("Guest " + h.id + " came inside room " + busy + " with " + rooms[busy].size() + " people");
    }

    void quit(Guest h) {

        if (rooms[busy].size() == 1) {
            setHandler(busy, h);
        } else {
            rooms[busy].remove(h);
            System.out
                    .println("Guest " + h.id + " came out of room " + busy + " with " + rooms[busy].size() + " people");
        }

    }

    synchronized void setHandler(int numQuarto, Guest ultimo) {
        System.out.println("(Last) Guest " + ultimo.id + " came out of room " + busy + " with "
                + rooms[numQuarto].size() + " people");
        rooms[numQuarto].remove(ultimo);
        busy = -1;
    }

}

class Room extends ArrayList<Guest> {
}
```

Comment: The strategy you describe won't prevent starvation. If a room always has people in it, no one who wants a different room will ever get a turn.

Comment: Perhaps by using only one thread?  I don't see why the problem requires multithreading.

Comment: every new guest must be a thread, and in the code, they are not starving, but they are not choosing the room they want, they just join and quit the room with people inside until it's empty... thats why its wrong

Comment: I agree with @JohnBollinger. Using multiple threads will cause starvation because only one room can be in use at a time. You should instead employ a queue and just use the main thread. To created guests, just randomly generate them with another thread

Comment: Supposing no one stays forever, the goal is avoiding them to starve

Comment: Seems more like an example of a thread scheduling problem where only one read-only resource can be allocated at any one time. Still, the only way to prevent starvation is with preemption, limited time quantum or similar.

Comment: Why do you care if a thread starves? Why do you care which threads get the resource? You should only care about what work gets done, not what thread does work.

Comment: the guest must join the room, this is the work to be done, if it starve, then the work fails

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this with threads -- which is highly artificial, but I suppose it is an exercise -- you need to learn how to make a `Thread` wait on a condition, and how to notify one or more `Threads` that the condition they are waiting for may have been satisfied.  Conveniently, every object has methods `wait()`, `notify()`, and `notifyAll()` that serve these purposes.

One important consideration with wait / notify is that you must be careful to wait on and notify the correct object.  Generally, that's *not* the `Thread` you want to be affected, but rather some shared object that all threads involved rely upon for mutual synchronization.  In this particular case, it looks like `Guest.rooms` would do nicely.

The general idea would be that in `Rooms.join()`, the current thread tests whether it can immediately take a room.  If so, it does, and continues as now.  If not, however, it invokes `wait()` (on the `Rooms` instance, which at that point is `this`).  Whenever that `wait()` returns, the thread must again check whether it can immediately take the room it wants; if not, it must wait again.

The other half would be in `Rooms.quit()`.  Whenever a thread running that method is the last one out of the room, it must reset `busy` to indicate that no room is occupied, and then, importantly, invoke `notifyAll()` to let all threads waiting at that time know that there's a chance to get a room.

You will find that you need to employ proper synchronization for this.  In particular, you can invoke `wait()` and `notifyAll()` (and `notify()`) only while holding the monitor of the target object (it will be released for the duration of the wait, and reacquired before wait() returns).  You will also need to ensure that you properly synchronize all manipulation of shared objects, however, in this case mainly the `Rooms` and its members, without preventing threads from proceeding when otherwise they could.  In particular, be aware that threads that `sleep()` *do not* for that reason release any monitors they may hold.

The rest is up to you.  I've given you rather a lot more of a hint than maybe I should, but it truly is a bit tricky to learn how to use wait / notify properly.

Comment: Unless I'm missing an implied point, you give a lot of good info but don't explain how it could prevent starvation.

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils - It won't >>prevent<< starvation, but it will reduce the probability to "vanishingly small".  You can only prevent starvation by leveraging (hypothetical) fair thread scheduling ... or implementing it yourself; e.g. with a priority queue so that the "longest waiting" guest gets priority if there is contention.

Comment: I tried to do with priority queue but I realized it gets a sequential approach instead of concurrent, and I wanted it to be concurrent

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils, you are right -- this approach does not prevent starvation, but as StephenC said, the likelihood is vanishingly small.  That's actually because starvation in this case would require an infinite sequence of guests and for `Random.nextInt()` to produce a grossly non-uniform distribution.  But that's anyway not the OP's real problem.  He says in comments: "they are not starving, but they are not choosing the room they want, they just join and quit the room with people inside until it's empty... thats why its wrong."  That's the main problem I address.

Comment: @Daniel - you need to use the priority queue the right way.  But as John Bollinger points out, starvation is not your real problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can't. Based on what you've given, other mechanisms would need to be implemented which guarantee no starvation can occur. For example,

> Guests (Threads) come in and out the whole time.

So, it's possible that *n* threads come in for Room *m* possibly the whole time. It's possible, too, that during that time more threads come in wanting another room. However, they cannot access the room until Room *m* is first emptied (which may never actually happen). This can continue for any number of rooms and threads. This is the case even if...

> For simplicity, suppose that, once the Guest comes inside a room, it
>   sleeps for some seconds and then get out.

And that's because...

> C can go to Room 1, because the Room C wants is the only Room with
>   people inside;

Which implies that another thread may enter an already occupied room with one or more threads with *t* time left to sleep. The new thread goes to sleep and won't wake up until after the previous one. While sleeping *n* more threads may enter the room potentially causing other threads waiting for other rooms to starve.

Comment: with starvation, i meant a scenary where its impossible to a thread to get to the room. yeah, a lot of threads can stop another thread to go to another room, but one time they will get out... i mean, this won't make impossible, you know? statistically, impossible is 0%, but this situation is not 0%

Comment: even if it takes forever